# Why do predatory mites have to be introduced multiple times?

Tags: ecology, predation

I'm combating spider mite infestation using either *Phytoseiulus persimilis* or *Amblyseius californicus*. After extensive study of the literature, I'm still unsure why the producers of these predatory mites suggest that they have to be introduced several times (2-3 times depending on manufacturer). I know that adult predatory mites are very agile and scout for new prey. *Phytoseiulus* is also known to wipe out spider mite populations. So as long as spider mites are present, why should one introduce them at intervals rather than just introduce a large number of predatory mites at the beginning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right that ideally it should be enough to apply them once, but predatory mites seem to be quite sensitive: If it gets too cold or too hot or the moisture is too low, they might die.

I applied several rounds of predatory mites in non-optimal conditions without any success. They just kept disappearing without any effect whatsoever. Funnily, some small type of Heteroptera came to save my plants. (from nature without my doing)

Next time I would try some Chryson instead.

Comment: Thanks for the input. This paper (https://www.eje.cz/pdfs/eje/1993/01/02.pdf)  suggests that P. persimilis can even survive temperatures below zero for brief periods of time. I think the problem is that it takes to long for the beneficials to arrive, because they are produced in the Netherlands and shipped to the distributor so it can take up two 2 weeks for the benefials to reach the target destination. Also a big producer (entocare) lists the shelf-life of 1 day.

Comment: OK, I see. From a non-biological and rather economical standpoint, it's always advantageous for companies to recommend triple use: They make more profit, there is a higher chance of success due to the duration of time alone, and it shuts down customer complaints, if it doesn't work the first attempt.